# Convert R GET method into Python

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, python-requests, httr

I am new to Python; currently, I need to convert the below R code to Python, I know I need to use requests library; however, I don`t know how to convert the `authenticate(cibc_username, cibc_password,"gssnegotiate")` into Python. So, could anyone help me to resolve it?

The R code below:

```
hr_page = GET(url, user_agent("""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko\)
Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"""), authenticate(cibc_username, cibc_password,"gssnegotiate"), timeout(20000))
```

What I write:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
data = {'username':cibc_username, 'password':cibc_password}
hr_page = requests.get(url, headers = headers, data = data, timeout = 20000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the auth method is indeed `gssapi`, you may need to use `HTTPNegotiateAuth` from `requests_negotiate`:

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate import HTTPNegotiateAuth

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout = 20000, auth=HTTPNegotiateAuth(cibc_username,cibc_password))
```

More info [here](https://github.com/ox-it/requests-negotiate)